# Slider makes images visible using values from objects as criteria in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, conditional-statements

I have a slider on a website and by sliding it, images disappear and appear. This is done by conditional statements.

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 300,
        max: 3000,
        values: [300, 3000],
        step: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
            var handlevalues = ($("#slider-range").slider('values'));
            var object0001={price:1300}
            var object0002={price:1400}
            var object0003={price:1240}
            if (object0001.price > handlevalues[0] && object0001.price < handlevalues[1]) {
                $("#dot0001").css("visibility", "visible");
            } else {
                $("#dot0001").css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            if (object0002.price > handlevalues[0] && object0002.price < handlevalues[1]) {
                $("#dot0002").css("visibility", "visible");
            } else {
                $("#dot0002").css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            if (object0003.price > handlevalues[0] && object0003.price < handlevalues[1]) {
                $("#dot0003").css("visibility", "visible");
            } else {
                $("#dot0003").css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is: there are more than 100 images and corresponding objects and it would take ages to add all of them and would make my code far to long. On top of that I will add and remove images daily. Is there a way of making this shorter?
This is what I thought of but I don't have the knowledge to do it.

I want jQuery to identify all objects with a name that start with "object" and have a value of property "price"  that is within the range of the slider. To make this easier we say this is set1.

Then I want jQuery to find all id´s that start with "dot" and finish with the same 4 digit numbers as the objects in set 1 and make them visible and all other images with an id that starts with "dot" to be invisible.

Example using the given codes: jQuery scans and finds that `object0001.price= 1300`. Then jquery looks for image that has `id=dot0001`. If `object0001.price=1300` is within the range of the slider image with `id=dot0001` becomes visible and if it isn't it becomes hidden.

Any help appreciated. If there is a question, I am right here.

Comment: likely much simpler solutions if you provide some sample html showing layout of images and the attributes they have

Comment: also help to see how all the `object` items are created. Format shown is not very code friendly

Comment: Okay, added the part where the objects are set

Comment: Why, instead of update one of your previous **identical** questions ([Q#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419297/jquery-slider-makes-images-visible-if-respective-object-properties-are-within-ra), [Q#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418724/conditional-statement-with-jquerys-range-slider-making-images-visible-hidden)) you open another one for the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a solution that has you inserting the item price as a `data-` attribute in html, generated I assume by server code.

For demo purpose I used a `DIV` with price as text. Items have a common class name , no ID's are needed.

```
<div class="item" data-price="320">320</div>
```

Slide code could still use a little optimizing but until sure that this is how module needs to work here is demo code:

```
/* cache items */
var $items=$('.item'), $max=$('#max'), $min=$('#min');

$("#slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 300,
        max: 800,
        values: [300,800],
        step: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var min=ui.values[0],max=ui.values[1];
            /* show slider values in min/max spans*/
            updateDisplayValues( max,min);  
            /* changing class more efficient than inline css*/          
            $items.removeClass('hidden').filter(function(){
                var price= $(this).data('price');  
                /* filter items that fall outside of range*/              
                return price < min || price> max;
            }).addClass('hidden');
        }
});

function updateDisplayValues( max,min){
    $max.text('Max: '+ max);
    $min.text('Min: '+ min);
}
```

CSS:

```
.item.hidden{
    visibility:hidden
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SPkD9/3/)**

There are several other simple methods to get data into page if needed such as loading all data in JSON array

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var allObjects = [
        object0001:{price:1300},
        object0002:{price:1400},
        object0003:{price:1240}
    ];
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 300,
        max: 3000,
        values: [300, 3000],
        step: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var priceMin, priceMax, objectName, objectStep, dotName, dotStep, visible;
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
            var handlevalues = ($("#slider-range").slider('values'));
            priceMin = handlevalues[0];
            priceMax = handlevalues[1];
            for ( objectName in allObjects ) {
                if ( allObjects.hasOwnProperty(objectName) ) {
                    objectStep = allObjects[objectName];
                    dotName = objectName.replace("object","dot");
                    dotStep = $("#"+dotName);
                    visible = (objectStep.price > priceMin && objectStep.price < priceMax);
                    dotStep.toggle(visible);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This precisely answers your question, but requires you craft both the dot objects and the allObjects JSON object.  It would be even cleaner to put the object's price as a `data-price` attribute on the dot object, and rather than looping through allObjects, loop through `$("[id^='dot']")`

Comment: not efficient using `$("#slider-range").slider('values')` within slide event handler when values array already available as `ui.values`

Comment: Yes, there are many inefficient things in the question's code sample, not the least of which is the question at hand: avoiding the redundant if/else for each item in the list.

Comment: that's why I went a completely different route with my solution, OP knows needs a more scalable methodology